# load image from the next 2 divs

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a impress.js slideshow file with the following content:

```
<div id="impress">
    <div class="step image" data-x="-1000" data-y="-1500" data-scale="1" data-content-duration="10000" data-content="image">
        <img class="backgroundImage" src="content/images/wallpaper-1013331.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="step image" data-x="920" data-y="-1500" data-scale="1" data-content-duration="10000" data-content="image">
        <img class="backgroundImage" src="content/images/wallpaper-1617202.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="step image" data-x="2840" data-y="-1500" data-scale="1" data-content-duration="10000" data-content="image">
        <img class="backgroundImage" src="content/images/wallpaper-1654260.jpg" />
    </div>

....
</div>
```

But I have 30 images and the browser get stuck with so much image. How can I, from first step, load next image, and then from second step, load next image and so on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the pictures with Javascript and use the recursion like this:

```
var arrayImg = { };
arrayImg[0] = { idImgElement: "id1", url: "url1" };
arrayImg[1] = { idImgElement: "id2", url: "url2" };
arrayImg[2] = { idImgElement: "id3", url: "url3" };
function loadImage(it) {
   "use strict";
   if (arrayImg[it]) {
      var imgObj = new Image();
      imgObj.src = arrayImg[it].url;
      imgObj.onload = function() {
         document.getElementById(arrayImg[it].idImgElement).src = this.src;
         loadImage(it + 1);
      }
   }
}
loadImage(0);
```

Write this script in the end of your html page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a different approach. I use data attribute data-src="path/to/image", and with help of impress.js events, I put the path image into the src img attribute. gist: https://gist.github.com/vitorcarvalhoml/0509cd8a136898e369bc